# Disable Export To Excel Option (Lists, Sharepoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel, export

How can be "Export to Excel" button (or option) disabled within lists in SharePoint Online?

I have tried disabling ["Use Client Integration Features"](https://serverfault.com/questions/73677/disable-export-to-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-custom-list) in the definition of the permission level, but the option remains there for the user.

Comment: try to add list on a page and hide menu from the view.

Comment: I would have to ask why you would want to do this! If they can see the data then what's the issue? It's easy to hide with css but that only works as long as MS doesn't change the classes around.

Comment: @spevilgenius In some cases it may be that the "Export to Excel" option allows users to circumvent audience targeting or other measures designed to selectively hide list data.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling "Use Client Integration Features" should disable the button, but not hide it. As others have said, to remove the button from the Ribbon completely you would need to alter the CSS of the page, but this may not even be possible in the Modern Experience.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to locate the CSS class responsible for displaying and then you can override the class with

> display: none;

this would do the same. You can add any html web part and add this style sheet in that HTML code , Hope it would help resolve.